# Limites en la cantidad de BD que puede manejar motor de PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Estoy diseñando una BD en Postgres para un sistema de Gestion Comercial Online. Aqui me surgen dos opciones:

- Tener una sola base de datos con los todos los datos de los clientes, y en todas las tablas agregar una columna con el ID del cliente para filtrar solo sus datos.
- Que cada cliente que se da de alta tenga su propia base de datos con solo sus datos.

Me parece mas ordenado la segunda opcion, y asi no mezclar datos de clientes diferentes en una misma tabla. Tambien me parece que el rendimiento de la BD sera mejor si tiene que consultar en tablas de menor tamaño, pero esto es solo una suposicion, ya que al tener muchas bases de datos siendo cosultadas a la vez no se si el motor disminuye su rendimiento.

La consulta es, suponiendo que la cantidad de clientes crezca, y optara porque cada uno tenga su propia base de datos,

hay algun límite sobre la cantidad de BD que Postgres puede manejar? 
Y sobre el rendimiento?

sera superior consultar sobre varias bases de tamaño pequeño que si consultara sobre una sola base de datos de gran tamaño?

Comment: En lo que hace al limite de databases, no esta documentado un número, pero según lo que menciona esto https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2008/11/10/10000-databases-on-postgresql-cluster, el limite estaría dado por la cantidad de subcarpetas en un directorio, o sea es un límite dado por el sistema operativo más que por el motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira, en este momento es trivial decirle a una máquina con Linux que puede mantener millones de archivos abiertos, de manera que la cantidad de tablas, que a su vez existen como archivos, no es tema. Adicionalmente, Postgres mantiene en memoria una cantidad finita de datos, y por sobre eso, una cantidad finita de páginas (segmentos de datos en una tabla, índice, secuencia, etc) `visibles`.

Sin embargo, bajo el sistema de archivos `ext4` sólo puedes manejar hasta 64.000 subdirectorios. Esto significa que puedes tener 63.995 bases de datos. Los otros 5 son

- `.` un hard link al subdirectorio actual
- `..` un hard link al subdirectorio padre
- `postgres` plantilla por defecto
- `template1` plantilla alternativa 1
- `template2` plantilla alternativa 2

**¿Cómo saltarse esta restricción?**

Si usas la directiva [dir_nlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) puedes hacer que los hard links en realidad no cuenten para este límite. Por lo mismo, puedes hacer que algunas de tus bases de datos en realidad no estén físicamente bajo el directorio de postgres sino que estén en otro subdirectorio al cual postgres apunta con un hard link.

Pero no hay que complicarse con eso. Postgres de por sí soporta [tablespaces](http://postgresql.org/docs/10/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) que pueden residir físicamente en cualquier otra parte del disco.

**Planteamiento estratégico**

Aunque no es inusual implementar una estructura `multitenant`, depende mucho de los datos que quieras almacenar. Tanto en cantidad como en el grado de confidencialidad, puede que no debas almacenar todo junto. Es más, cuando implementas un sistema multitenant se vuelve casi imposible separar los datos si un día quisieras separar en distintas BBDD.

Si usas distintas bases de datos vas a tener que implementar una suerte de **instance registry** que emparente un cliente con su instancia de BBDD (se puede hacer con una tupla `cliente-PGurl`) alojada en otro lado. En el enfoque `convención por sobre configuración` el nombre sanitizado del cliente podría mapearse al nombre de una BBDD. Pero va a llegar el día en que quieras tener distintos clientes en distintas máquinas y ese enfoque no te va a servir.

Como dije antes, normativas sobre privacidad y seguridad, dependiendo de la clase de negocio, sobretodo si quieres certificarte en ISO 27001 (pensemos en grande) tienes que implementar algo más robusto que mezclar todo. El multitenant está perfecto para un sistema multiusuario, pero no tanto para un sistema multiempresa.

**Rendimiento**

Dependiendo del tamaño de las tablas que estés pensando, puede que haya una merma en rendimiento para consultas que no aprovechen bien los índices si es que metes todo en una misma BBDD. Pero si los índices y las queries están bien diseñadas, esa merma sería marginal. Adicionalmente, con el particionamiento incorporado en Postgres 10 y perfeccionado en Postgres 11, puedes abordar ese problema con particiones de tipo round robin. Para cualquier tabla que tenga la llave `cliente_id` (como planteas en la alternativa multitenant) puedes particionar por hash diciendo:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
cliente_id INTEGER, ...
) PARTITION BY HASH (cliente_id);

CREATE TABLE clientes_0 PARTITION OF clientes
FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0);

CREATE TABLE clientes_1 PARTITION OF clientes
FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 1);

CREATE TABLE clientes_2 PARTITION OF clientes
FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 2);
```

Por ley de los grandes números, los registros se dividirán en 3 más o menos en forma pareja. Postgres 11 optimiza las queries de tal manera que al hacer una consulta simplemente ignora las particiones que no pueden cumplir con la query, tan temprano como es posible.

Tanto si usas una gran BBDD como si usas muchas BBDDs, el tener muchos clientes conectados implica mantener muchos datos en memoria y muchos datos visibles, y eso ocurrirá en ambos casos.

La diferencia va por el lado de la estrategia. Si separas de antemano e implementas el instance registry, después podrás crecer horizontalmente añadiendo más máquinas en vez de engordando la máquina principal.

Eso, y finalmente el viejo adagio de los huevos en la misma canasta...

**Bonus Track: el mapeo via capa de negocios**

Una vez implementé un sistema en donde la piedra de tope no era la estructura relacional, que obedecía a 3NF. Era el hecho de que un cliente podía subir N tablas de datos con columnas arbitrarias que eran sus "colecciones personales", como quien sube planillas a google drive.

Como no hay una manera de mantener una integridad relacional entre un cliente y sus tablas usando entidades del catálogo de postgres como `pg_tables`, no puedes usar la lógica de la base de datos de por sí para que, dada la eliminación de un cliente, se haga drop a las tablas que subió. Tienes que usar la capa de negocios para relacionar un cliente con sus tablas, y borrarlas antes de borrar a un clientes.

Como resultado, la capa de negocios queda absolutamente acoplada a la capa de persistencia, y la idea es que las capas de una aplicación no necesiten saber más que lo mínimo sobre la implementación de las capas adyacentes.

(actualmente alguien me diría que en vez de tener N tablas por cliente, tuviera una tabla en donde cada registro tuviera un campo de tipo JSONB que contuviera una cierta colección de datos para el dueño de esa fila... lo cual estaría casi bien, salvo porque se trataba de tablas geoespaciales que requerían filtrar utilizando PostGIS. Postgres no tiene índices espaciales para estructuras GeoJSON como sí tiene MongoDB)